# Iterate through nested dictionary of type String: Any

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, object

So basically I'm trying to build a financial app for myself using an external api.

I successfully decoded the json response and stored the object into a dictionary of type [String: Any]. Here is my sample output for my portfolio: I stored this as a Published variable

```
     "accounts" : [
       {
         "position" : some_number_of_shares,
         "avgCost" : some_decimal_number,
         "contract" : {
           "symbol" : "someString",
           "currency" : "USD",
           "conID" : some_Integer,
           "exchange" : "someString",
           "tradingClass" : "someString",
           "localSymbol" : "someString"
         },
         "account" : "someString"
       },
       {
         "position" : some_number_of_shares,
         "avgCost" : some_decimal_number,
         "contract" : {
           "tradingClass" : "someString",
           "exchange" : "someString",
           "localSymbol" : "someString",
           "symbol" : "someString",
           "currency" : "USD",
           "conID" : some_Integer
         },
         "account" : "someString"
       }
     ]
   }
```

I'm trying to display all of this information through a simple for i in loop, however it always gives me some error about subscripts, or something about casting. here is my loop

```
for (key) in self.apicall.positions["accounts"]! {
    print(key["account"])
    print(type(of: key))
}
```

I got multiple errors with this loop, but if I removed the key["account"] then I got

```
Position(avgCost: someFloat, account: "someString", position: someShares, contract: MyFirebase.Contract(exchange: "someString", currency: "someString", symbol: "someString", tradingClass: "someString", localSymbol: "someString", conID: someNumber))
Position

Position(avgCost: someFloat, account: "someString", position: someShares, contract: MyFirebase.Contract(exchange: "someString", currency: "someString", symbol: "someString", tradingClass: "someString", localSymbol: "someString", conID: someNumber))
Position
```

I tried treating this as an object too but it wouldn't allow me. Let me know if you need an error message to debug this for me if I'm missing something absurdly obvious lol

Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! So basically all I had to do was to fix my Published dictionary from:

```
@Published var positions = [String: [Any]]()
```

to:

```
@Published var positions = [String: [Position]]()
```

where my Position was a struct where I decoded my JSON Response.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think using a dictionary to store your api response is the right approach. We have the codable protocol to conform decoded JSON types to model objects. That would make debugging a bit easier, and would also clean up the code

Second, in your scenario, "key" will give you an index because "accounts" is of type array of objects. So you need to get the value, and then get the key

```
for index in self.apicall.positions["accounts"]! {
    let position = self.apicall.positions["accounts"]![index]
    // Here you can loop through the key, value of position object
    let avgCost = position["avgCost"]
    print(avgCost)
    print(type(of: avgCost))
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response! I tried that before too but I get the following error at the 'let position =...' line: "No exact matches in call to subscript". I've been seeing this error many times and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Further more. there is some additional info on the error: 1. Candidate expects value of type 'Int' for parameter #1 (Swift.Array)  2. Candidate expects value of type 'Range<Int>' for parameter #1 (Swift.Array)  3. Candidate expects value of type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()' for parameter #1 (Swift.Collection)   4. Candidate expects value of type 'Range<Array<Any>.Index>' (aka 'Range<Int>') for parameter #1 (Swift.MutableCollection)   5. Candidate expects value of type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()' for parameter #1 (Swift.MutableCollection)